# Basic probability. Is the textbook wrong?

Tags: probability, intuition

A and B are independent events such that 
P(A)=0.7,  P(B)=k,  P(A U B)=0.8
Find the value of k.

Solution given:

P(A U B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A ∩ B).....(i) [Addition Rule]

P(A ∩ B) = P(A).P(B).....(ii)   [Multiplication rule]

Substituing (ii) in (i),

P(A U B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A).P(B)

0.8 = 0.7 + k - 0.7k

0.1 = 0.3k

Hence k = 1/3

I find this solution wrong because I think we cannot just substitue the multiplication rule in the addition rule because the **intersections in both the rules mean different things.**

In the additon rule, *intersection* refers to **an outcome that satisfies both the events**.

In multiplication rule, *intersection* refers to **one event happening after another**.

Example:
If A={2,3} and B={3,9}

Addition rule:
A∩B = {3}

Multiplication rule:
A∩B = {(2,3), (2,9), (3,3), (3,9)}

Comment: Intersection of two sets *always* means the same thing; it means what you have written in the "addition rule."  There is no separate intersection for the multiplication rule.

Comment: There is only one correct interpretation for intersection. No difference for addition or multiplication.

Comment: The addition rule helped us solve problems when we performed one task and wanted to know the probability of two things happening during that task. The multiplication rule also deals with two events, but in these problems the events occur as a result of more than one task (rolling one die then another, drawing two cards, spinning a spinner twice, pulling two marbles out of a bag, etc). So the question is, is the addition rule applicable to two or more tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intersection means the same thing in both cases: That the intersection $A\cap B$ occurs means just that both events occur, or if you like, the outcome "satisfies both".

If $A=\{2,3\}$ and $B=\{3,9\}$ then $A\cap B = \{3\}$ and $A\times B = \{(2,3),(2,9),(3,3),(3,9)\}$.  This latter product is the **Cartesian product, not the intersection.**

Suppose an experiment yields $1$, $2$, or $3$, and an independent replication also yields $1$, $2$, or $3$.  Then the set of possible outcomes of the sequence of two experiments is the Cartesian product:
$$
\{1,2,3\}\times\{1,2,3\} = \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} (1,1), & (1,2), & (1,3), \\ (2,1), & (2,2), & (2,3), \\ (3,1), & (3,2), & (3,3)\phantom{,} \end{array} \right\}.
$$
Suppose the event $A$ is that either a $1$ or a $2$ appears on the first trial, and the event $B$ is that a $1$ appears on the second trial.  Then
$$
A = \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} (1,1), & (1,2), & (1,3), \\ (2,1), & (2,2), & (2,3)\phantom{,} \end{array} \right\} \text{ and } B= \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} (1,1), \\ (2,1), \\ (3,1)\phantom{,} \end{array} \right\}.
$$
The intersection is just the set of outcomes in both $A$ and $B$, meaning both events occur:
$$
A\cap B = \left\{ \begin{array}{c} (1,1), \\ (2,1)\phantom{,} \end{array} \right\}.
$$

Comment: Thank you, Sir. What would be the correct way to visualize the individual probabilities in addition rule for the latter part of the answer (two indentical experiments)?

P(B) = n(B) ÷ n(S)
         =  {1} ÷ {1,2,3}
         = 1/3

OR

P(B) = n(B) ÷ n(S)
         = {(1,1), (1,2), (1,3)} ÷ {(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3)}
         = 3/9
         = 1/3

The answers are the same, but I think the second perception (ordered pairs) is the correct one, because it is in line with A ∩ B which is also a set of ordered pairs.

Comment: @DhruvGupta : Either of those is correct.  Which is appropriate might depend on your purpose or on what information you have. $\qquad$